# How can I solve $y''=x^{-1/3}y^{3/2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation.

$$y''=x^{-1/3}y^{3/2}$$

I tried the solution: $y=Ax^s$

$$\implies y'=Asx^{s-1} \\ \iff y''=As(s-1)x^{s-2}$$

$$\implies As(s-1)x^{s-2}= x^{-1/3}(Ax^s)^{3/2} \\ \iff As(s-1)x^{s-2}=x^{-1/3}A^{3/2}x^{\frac{3s}{2}} \\ \iff A^{5/2}s(s-1)=x^{-1/3}x^{3s/2}x^{2-s} \\ \iff Cs(s-1)=x^{\frac{3s}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+2-s} \\ \iff Cs(s-1)=x^{\frac{1}{6}(9s-2+12-6s)}\\ \iff Cs(s-1)=x^{\frac{1}{6}(3s+10)} \\ \iff \ln(Cs^2-Cs)=\frac{1}{6}(3s+10)\ln(x) \\ \iff \ln(C)+\ln(s^2-s)=\frac{1}{6}(3s+10)\ln(x)$$

I am stuck here and I don't know if this is even the best approach. I even tried to solve it with Mathematica but I got no answer. How do I solve this equation?

Comment: Note that $x$ is a free variable so if you do such a calculation and end up with $1 = x(a-2) + b$ (just an example) then we must have $a=2$ and $b=1$. Apply this to your calculation to determine $A$ and $s$. btw I think there are some algebra mistakes in what you have done so I would double check the calculation if I were you.

Comment: OP did make some mistakes, but it's irrelevant in the end since $A$ is a constant and he relabeled it with $C$ anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Could you maybe point out where I made a mistake. Is this even the right approach for solving this ODE?

Comment: The only small mistake is the way you move $A^{3/2}$ between lines 4 and 5, but like i said, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It does matter as there is only one real value of $A$ for which there is a solution; $A$ is not a free constant. "Is this even the right approach": Well this is one method to find *a* solution. This ODE is non-linear and for non-linear equations most of the methods are out the window. It's very few non-linear ODEs where one can find analytical solutions at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the form of the Emden-Fowler equation, $y'' = Ax^ny^m$. For $m\neq1$, the solution is
\begin{equation*}
y = Cx^{\frac{n+2}{1-m}}
\end{equation*}
for a constant $C$ that depends on $A$, $n$, and $m$. In your case, the solution is $y = Cx^{\frac{5/3}{-1/2}} = Cx^{-10/3}$. You would have gotten this constant also by requiring $\frac16(3s+10) = 0$, as mentioned by @Winther. Indeed, $y' = C\frac{-10}3x^{-13/3}$, $y'' = C\frac{-10}3\frac{-13}3x^{-16/3}$, and $x^{-1/3}y^{3/2} = x^{-1/3}A^{3/2}x^{-10/2} = A^{3/2}x^{-16/3}$ and so setting $C = \frac{-3}{10}\cdot\frac{-3}{13}\cdot A^{3/2}$ will give you the desired solution.